# Howto initialize a reference to an object if reference is a class member?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, persistence, member

Let's say *Class* contains a reference called *matrix_*:

Class.h

```
class Class
{
Matrix& matrix_;
}
```

Class.cpp

```
Class::Class() : matrix_(Matrix())
{
}
```

I get the error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘Matrix&’ from a 
 temporary of type ‘Matrix’.

I see that the problem is that the temporary object will disappear and the reference will point to NULL. How can I create a persistent object for the reference? I want to use a reference because this member should be constant.

Comment: you can't bind rvalue to non-const reference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Class::Class() : matrix_(Matrix())` tries to set the reference to point to a temporary object, which is illegal.

*well, there's a case with const references and temporary binding, but seriously, don't go there.*

Looks like you just need to use aggregation:

```
class Class
{
const Matrix matrix_;
};
```

And the initializer list:

```
Class::Class() : matrix_() /* or any params to the constructor if you need them */
{
}
```

Comment: +1 for keeping it simple :) You might want to add a semi-colon after the class definition (I'd do it for you, but not enough rep). Looks like a propagated error from the original question...

Comment: I forgot that I can make it this easy.

Comment: @sgolodetz, Absolutely right, I'll fix this right away just for clarity. :)

Answer (score 3):

The Matrix reference must be provided as an argument of all constructors of Class.

```
class Class
{
  Matrix & matrix_;
public:
  Class(Matrix & matrix);
};

Class::Class(Matrix & matrix) : matrix_(matrix)
{
}
```

Note that although the reference will be constant (C++ references are constant pointers), the referenced Matrix will not, unless you add a const specifier.

Comment: matrix_ is private so that is not an option ufortunately

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that references are not meant to be used for this. They are to be used more as an "alias" for something already existing. Be it an anonymous stack object (whose life is controlled by the codes scope) or a heap object with its own already existing pointer. In your case you are trying to use reference only for its constant property but forget that its more than a constant pointer.

The appropriate solution would be to use a constant pointer and allocate the new object on the heap like this:

Class.h

```
class Class
{
Matrix* const matrix_;
}
```

Class.cpp

```
Class::Class() : matrix_(new Matrix())
{
}
```

Comment: I answered my own question because it came to me while thinking about the question and I wanted to share this with others faced with the same problem. I am not sure if it's correct though.

Comment: Or just create it as a value and forget about indirection.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use a reference for this member to be constant.  You could use `boost::scoped_ptr<const Matrix>`.

```
class Class
{
public:
    Class();
private:
    boost::scoped_ptr<const Matrix> _matrix;
}

Class::Class() : _matrix(new Matrix)
{
}
```

Comment: I'm curious as to why you suggest boost::scoped_ptr instead of std::auto_ptr?

Comment: @awoodland - purely habit, I rarely use `auto_ptr`

Comment: I was worried there was some good reason to favour it over auto_ptr that I'd not noticed before

Comment: @awoodland - I think my aversion to `auto_ptr` stems from usage of the VC6 version (the one you can make a `vector` of).

Comment: @awoodland: the semantics are slightly different, and using a `scoped_ptr` ensures that there is no generated `operator=` (If you use a `std::auto_ptr` and then write `Class a, b; a = b;` the compiler will gladly generate an assignment operator that releases the internal pointer in `a`, and then transfers ownership from `b` to `a`, leaving `b` empty handed.

Comment: @david so it's like the const auto_ptr idiom then?

Comment: @awoodland: Not really, it disables the weird behavior of unintentional copies, but it allows you to `reset` the pointed element (if needed) or to `swap` the pointer. In most cases I have not needed the `reset` at all, but being able to `swap` the contents of two objects is a simple step towards the strong exception guarantee (idiom for exception guarantees: operate aside on a copy, if succeeded swap contents. The original object only gets changed through `swap` that is a no throw operation).